# Converting character in to date format in R - Issue with few rows returning NA

Tags: r

I have tried to convert characters into date format using the `library(lubridate`), using
`cp3m$date <- mdy(cp3m$Date),` Warning message: 1071 failed to parse`.

Now dataset looks like this

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Date      PX_LAST date      
  <chr>       <dbl> <date>    
1 3/13/2018    7.74 2018-03-13
2 43437        7.79 NA        
3 43346        7.82 NA        
4 43315        7.84 NA        
5 43284        7.92 NA        
6 43254        7.93 NA        
7 43223        7.88 NA        
8 43103        7.88 NA        
9 2/28/2018    7.92 2018-02-28
```

Any help on how to go about removing this NA and getting a date format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates are in mixed format, one are in the format `mdy` and another one are excel dates. You can apply two different techniques on the dates.

Here is a base R approach -

```
df$date <- as.Date(NA)
only_number <- grepl('^\\d+$', df$Date)
df$date[only_number] <- as.Date(as.numeric(df$Date[only_number]), origin="1899-12-30")
df$date[!only_number] <- as.Date(df$Date[!only_number], '%m/%d/%Y')
df
#       Date PX_LAST       date
#1 3/13/2018    7.74 2018-03-13
#2     43437    7.79 2018-12-03
#3     43346    7.82 2018-09-03
#4     43315    7.84 2018-08-03
#5     43284    7.92 2018-07-03
#6     43254    7.93 2018-06-03
#7     43223    7.88 2018-05-03
#8     43103    7.88 2018-01-03
#9 2/28/2018    7.92 2018-02-28
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("3/13/2018", "43437", "43346", "43315", 
"43284", "43254", "43223", "43103", "2/28/2018"), PX_LAST = c(7.74, 
7.79, 7.82, 7.84, 7.92, 7.93, 7.88, 7.88, 7.92)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah. It's working but the initial date was 28/03/2018 now it has changed to 28/03/2020 and previously wherever there was *NA* the format has now become 'yy-dd-mm'.

Comment: That should not happen. Can you share the sample of your data in a reproducible format using `dput` ?

Comment: My sample has 2709 entries. Guess the provided character in this comment section will not be adequate. I have provided extracts of that data in the question. The time period is 02/01/2007 - 28/03/2018. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need to share entire 2709 enteries, share only the ones which returns an error. Also it would be helpful if you share data in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Answer (score 0):

Use library `janitor`, from the place/step after your incomplete dates retreival.

```r
df

       Date PX_LAST       date
1 3/13/2018    7.74 2018-03-13
2     43437    7.79       <NA>
3     43346    7.82       <NA>
4     43315    7.84       <NA>
5     43284    7.92       <NA>
6     43254    7.93       <NA>
7     43223    7.88       <NA>
8     43103    7.88       <NA>
9 2/28/2018    7.92 2018-02-28

library(janitor)

df$date[is.na(df$date)] <- janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(df$Date[is.na(df$date)]))

df
#>        Date PX_LAST       date
#> 1 3/13/2018    7.74 2018-03-13
#> 2     43437    7.79 2018-12-03
#> 3     43346    7.82 2018-09-03
#> 4     43315    7.84 2018-08-03
#> 5     43284    7.92 2018-07-03
#> 6     43254    7.93 2018-06-03
#> 7     43223    7.88 2018-05-03
#> 8     43103    7.88 2018-01-03
#> 9 2/28/2018    7.92 2018-02-28
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I have posted some portions of the dataset. Nothing changed after running the code. Thanks

Comment: You are right. I have neither changed nor edited the question. In the above comment, I mean to say that I have provided some part of my data (not the entire dataset) in the question. My sample has 2709 entries, the time period is 02/01/2007 - 28/03/2018. I have provided extracts of that data in the question. I run the code again. The only problem now is the format has changed from **yyyy-mm-dd** to **yyyy-dd-mm**. **Please see your solution above**.  The date format has changed Thanks for your help.

Comment: in your output `3/13/2018`, is shown as `2018-03-13`, whereas `43437` is shown as `2018-12-03` instead of `2018-03-12`, `43103` is shown as `2018-01-03` instead of `2018-03-01`. Hope it makes things clear now. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @AnilGoyal, The date is not 3-Jan-2018 rather it is `01-Mar-2018`. This is what I am trying to explain to you. Please see the first row and last row of my question. First-row starts with March and the last row is February. All the `NA` observations have to be `March` or `Feb` because the complete data set is in descending order. So there will be January only after we finish the February days. This is day-wise observation, (weekends and holidays are excluded). Hope this explains. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @learning_r, have you rechecked the date? `43101` is indeed `3- Jan` .  I checked twice in EXCEL.  If it is `1-Mar` then it is again excel input/data entry error and should have been corrected in regional setiings itself before exporting the data.  Still, you may correct it by first identifying such mixed-up dates, convert ONLY these to character and reverse these in 2 steps using lubridate perhaps

Comment: Thanks@AnilGoyal. The data is downloaded from Bloomberg. While downloading in excel these are the formats I am getting. Maybe these errors have crept up while exporting to excel. I'll try changing regional settings. Hope that will solve the issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Actually, in the downloaded excel, there are two formats - 3/28/2018, and 03/12/18. After importing and applying  `df$date <- mdy(df$Date)`, the `03/12/18` format changed to`43437`, `43336`.. and so on. The `3/28/2018` converted to the actual date `3/28/2018`.

Answer (score 0):

From start to finish since I think it would look cleaner this way:

```
cp3m <- structure(list(Date = c("3/13/2018", "43437", "43346", "43315", 
"43284", "43254", "43223", "43103", "2/28/2018"), PX_LAST = c(7.74, 
7.79, 7.82, 7.84, 7.92, 7.93, 7.88, 7.88, 7.92)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")

cp3m %>%
  mutate(date = case_when(str_detect(Date, "^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$") ~ as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"),
                          str_detect(Date, "^[0-9]{5}$") ~ as.Date(as.numeric(Date), origin = "1899-12-30")))
```